# Selenium ElementClickInterceptedException Error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on this [website](https://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol=NICA)
Basically I want to capture 2 latest news from `News` section that is below the table and store that news in some json and collect picture if possible but I am not able to go to the news section as It always raise error saying

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CompanyDetail1_lnkNewsTab" href="#divNews"> is not clickable at point (307,786) because another element <iframe id="webpush-onsite" name="webpush-onsite"> obscures it`

here is some part of code I tried tough

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
stocks_data = ["AKPL","NICA"]

for stock_data in stocks_data:
     self.driver.get(f'https://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol= 
      {stock_data.lower()}')
      self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='navNews']"
                              "//a[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CompanyDetail1_lnkNewsTab']").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to click it regardless a normal user won't be able because as the error says, there's an IFrame on top of it...

Try the following:

1. Set the window size to 1920x1080 or so, maybe the elements overlap because the screen on Selenium's session is too small ‍♂️
2. Worst case scenario, inject some Javascript code to do it forcefully:

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CompanyDetail1_lnkNewsTab').click()")
```

3. Click on exact coordinate (x,y) if you know it ofcs.

Comment: thanks for answer but can you help me get further from there as I am not able to get those news as I want news in json form

Comment: I think it'll be a bit annoying in this format, hhh. Maybe just ask a new answer, because it's already kind of a different topic, with what you get, how you get it and what do you expect. (then maybe just ping me on that question, I'll try to help me best ^_^)

Comment: hi @Evgeny I have added new qsn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72774792/selenium-unable-to-process-further-after-executing-script

Comment: @nava, see answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72775070/2124529 :)