# Selenium Unable to process further after executing script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This question is actually continued from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72761041/selenium-elementclickinterceptedexception-error)
I have following [link](https://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol=akpl) I got help from community regarding using script in selenium
but main part here is I want to collect atleast 2-3 news and store in some json which can further be manipulated.
I am not able to click the  get those news section which is in bottom part of page any way I can scrape those news at least 1-2 new?

```
   stocks_data=["AKPL","NICA"]
   for stock_data in stocks_data:
            self.driver.get(f'https://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol={stock_data[0].lower()}')
            self.driver.execute_script(
                "document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CompanyDetail1_lnkNewsTab').click()")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use stocks_data=`["AKPL","NICA"]` instead of stocks_data=`"AKPL","NICA"]`

Answer (score 1):

As for the multiple news, just use a loop over `document.querySelectorAll('[id*="_lnkNewsTab"]')` or some similar selector if that one is too wide.

As for the json, try to populate some imaginary div (that you can create in Javascript by `document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="my_json"></div>'`) with the content of the elements you need (`document.getElementById('my_json').innerHTML += document.getElementById('the id of the element you want the data from').innerHTML;`) and finally get that div from python (see [How to get text with Selenium WebDriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python))

Then you can manipulate however you like in python.

Something like:

```
   stocks_data=["AKPL","NICA"]
   for stock_data in stocks_data:
            self.driver.get(f'https://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol={stock_data[0].lower()}')
            self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CompanyDetail1_lnkNewsTab').click()")
            self.driver.execute_script("""
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="my_json"></div>';
var x = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="_lnkNewsTab"]');
for (let i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  document.getElementById('my_json').innerHTML += x[i].innerHTML + '--DELIMITER--'
});
            """)
            content = self.driver.find_element_by_id("my_json")
            content = content.text.split('--DELIMITER--')[:-1]
```

Comment: ` ``self.driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('[id*=\"_lnkNewsTab\"]')")
                for z in self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='table table-striped table-hover']//tr//a"):
                    print(z.click())```
I did upto here but no result

Comment: I dont know js but I got this errro ` TypeError: x.map is not a function`

Comment: Fixed, edited answer

Comment: just a silly qsn what is content supposed to print?

Comment: I just got `NEWS` printed

Comment: content should hold an array of your collected "articles"

Comment: Also, can you run `document.querySelectorAll('[id*="_lnkNewsTab"]')` in DevTool and show me what it prints ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245958/discussion-between-nava-and-evgenykolyakov).